# Consuming a webservice with jsessionid in URL

Tags: web-services, soap, abap, jsessionid, sap-basis

I`m working on a SAP project, where i have to call a non-sap service with jsessionid in binding url. I already generated a proxy class out of the wsdl and defined a logical port with my URL. In my case it should be dynamic like: {host}/service/foo/binding;jsessionid={xxx} but its static like: {host}/service/foo/binding

How can i achieve that session handling?

EDIT: The problem here is, its not only for authentification its also for load balancing. The jsessionid MUST be submitted via URL rewriting. Any ideas?

Comment: doesn't the webservice support some authentication mechanisms like basic, digest or certificates? I think it's a little bit strange that you have to hand over the jsessionid while requesting...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to configure this with the soamanager transaction:

- Go to the service configuration screen and select your consumer proxy
- Edit the existing, or create a new logical port
- Go to the transport settings tab and change the URL access path

Once saved, you can find the logical port as a destination in transaction SM59. It's one of the generated ones in the external HTTP connections tree.

Providing a value for the parameter will probably require a modification of the SAP software though. The system uses the cl_http_client=>create_by_destination method to obtain a client object to perform the http call, so maybe you can implement some custom code there.